# How can I make the following graph?

Tags: graphics

I tried like this but it didn't work, any other suggestions or help, thank you very much.
[image]
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        &M:\hspace{1cm} M^{0} \hspace{1cm}\hspace{1cm} M^{1}\hspace{1cm} \cdots\hspace{1cm} M^{j}\hspace{1cm} \cdots \\
        &\downarrow_{f}
        &N
    \end{align*}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simple drawn by `tikz-cd` package dedicated to drawing of commutative diagrams:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.00cm,
            vmargin={2.00cm,3.00cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzcd}
M : \dar["f"]   
    & M^0 \drar["f^0"]  
        & M^1 \drar["f^1"]  
            & \dotsm 
                & M^i \drar["f^i"]  
                    & \dotsm 
                        &       \\
N : & N^0 \dots         
        & N^i   
            & N^{i+1}
                & \dots
                    & N^{j+1}
                        & \dots
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @SebastiánTobarCastro, you are welcome!

Comment: One last question, if I want an arrow that connects M^{0} with N^{0}, how would it be?

Comment: @SebastiánTobarCastro, you should read a package documentation ;-). In my solution I use shortened forms of writing arrows, described are on page 4 of documentation. This additional arrows you can add by `\dar` at node `M^{0}`.  Long form for this is `\arrow[d]`.

Comment: thank you very much for the help and information.